# Combining multiple rows with non-unique values into comma-separated value in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a Pandas dataframe that has values like

| Task | Skill | Technique | Technologies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | S1 | Technique 5 | Technology 4 |
| Second | S1 | Technique 1 | Technology 5 |
| Second | S1 | Technique 2 | Technology 5 |
| Third | S3 | Technique 1 | Technology 5 |
| Third | S3 | Technique 5 | Technology 4 |
| Third | S2 | Technique 1 | Technology 5 |
| Third | S2 | Technique 5 | Technology 4 |

I basically want to group them and aggregate the last three columns into comma-separated values such that it only has unique values separated by a comma.

| Task | Skill | Technique | Technologies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | S1 | Technique 5 | Technology 4 |
| Second | S1 | Technique 1, Technique 2 | Technology 5 |
| Third | S3, S2 | Technique 1, Technique 5 | Technology 5, Technology 4 |

I have tried grouping them in separate steps (1-column at a time) and all in one go, but it doesn't yield the desired result. Is there something better than groupby() that I can use?

Comment: `df.groupby('Task', as_index=False).agg(lambda s: ', '.join(s.unique()))`